# Nautilus Properties No Longer Shows 'Make Link' Option

Tags: nautilus, symbolic-link

I've searched pretty hard - but cannot find out how to make Nautilus in Ubuntu 17.10 show 'Make Link'on right clicking a directory, either directly or via Properties.
I'd like to set symlinks for use by Insync but since updating Ubuntu to 17.10 this option has disappeared.
Possibly it doesn't help that I'm now using Budgie-Ubuntu but even adding alternative desktop environments doesn't do the trick. (Not using Wayland, by the way...)
I just cannot understand why the devs would remove this option!
David

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be a duplication. I searched but did not find the original post. My apologies. However, not satisfacorily answered, it seems.

Comment: While I still have not found a simple answer to my question - I have found after looking at alternatives to Nautilus (and Thunar...) that Dolphin file manager does allow the creation of symlinks without having to resort to convoluted shenanigens via Bash. Though still not as simply as Nautilus used to offer! Thanks pomsky - David